Solve $\,n^{21}= 37\ldots 2719\ (53$ digits) for natural $n$
This is a problem $4$ of the "Bulgaria International
Mathematics Competition $2023$":

The $53$-digit number
$37,984,318,966,591,152,105,649,545,470,741,788,308,402,068,827,142,719$
can be expressed as $n^{21}$, where $n$ is a positive integer. What is
the value of $n$?

Since the unit digit of $n^{21}$ is $9$, I noticed that, the unit digit of $n$ must be $9$. Additionally, since $n^{21}$ is a $53$-digit number let's see what the number of digits is (for example) for $n=200$,$$200^{21}=2^{21}\times100^{21}=1024\times1024\times2\times10^{42}$$Hence $200^{21}$ has $49$ digits. Consequently, $n\ge 209$. I'm not sure how to continue from here.

Are you allowed to use some sort of technology?  I'd hate to do this by hand.  On the other hand, with a scientific calculator it's easy to show that $309^{21}$ is too small and $329^{21}$ too large.

@RobertIsrael I believe it is not allowed as it is a problem from Bulgaria International
Mathematics Competition 2023 and calculators and electronic devices are not allowed.

Since $\gcd(n,10)=1$ and Carmichael $\lambda(100)=20, n^{21}\equiv n\bmod100$; also $n$ is a multiple of $11$

...and there's only one multiple of $11$ between $200$ and $400$ ending with $\dots19$

@J.W.Tanner Your comment about using the Carmichael function is an excellent deduction. Note also that $n^{21}\equiv 1\pmod{9}$, so $n\neq 219$ since, otherwise, $n\equiv 3\pmod{9};\to;n^{21}\equiv 0\pmod{9}$. However, $319\equiv 1\pmod{9}$ does work.

In my comment above, it should be $319\equiv 4\pmod{9}$ does work, with this being because $319^{21}\equiv 4^{21}\equiv (4^3)^7\equiv 64^7\equiv 1^7\equiv 1\pmod{9}$.

Yes, @JohnOmielan, or $4^{21}\equiv(4^6)^34^3\equiv64\equiv1\pmod9$; actually $n^{21}\equiv1\pmod3$, so $n\ne219$; (actually $319\equiv4\pmod9$ does work)

@J.W.T Easier to use $400$ vs $100$ which also has $\lambda(400)=20,,$ so $\bmod 400!:\ n\equiv n^{21}\equiv 719\equiv 319\ \ $

In base $10$, $\log N \approx 52.58$ and $52.58/21 \approx 2.504$. We have $\log 316.2 \approx 2.5$ since $\sqrt{10} \approx 3.162$, and $\log 320 \approx 1+5\log 2 \approx 2.505$, so $319$ looks like a good bet. :-)

Simple way to discover it: $ $ by here we can easily take the $\,\color{#c00}{21}$'th root of $\,n^{\color{#c00}{21}}\equiv a\pmod{\!m}\,$ when $\,\color{#c00}{21}\,$ is coprime to Carmichael $\,\lambda(m),\,$ e.g. if $\,\color{#0af}{\lambda (m) = 20},\,$ e.g. if $\,m=400,\,$ yielding
$$\left[n^{\bf\color{#c00}{21}}\equiv a\right]^{\!\color{#c00}{\bf\Large\frac{1}{21}_{\phantom{|_{|}}}}}\!\!\!\!\!\! \underset{\large n^{\color{#0af}{20}}\ \equiv\ 1}\Longrightarrow\,  n\:\!\equiv\:\! a^{\color{#c00}{\bf\Large \frac{1}{21}}\!\bmod\color{#0af}{20}_{\phantom{|_{|_|}}}}\!\!\!\!\equiv a^{\large\color{#c00}{\bf 1}}\! \equiv\, \ldots{\bf \color{#fa0}{27}}19\:\!\equiv\:\! {\bf \color{#fa0}3}19\!\!\pmod{\!{\bf \color{#fa0}4}00}\qquad$$

Generally as above $,n^{21} = \rm \ldots {\bf\color{#fa0}{ab}}cd\overset{(n,10)=1}\Longrightarrow!!! !!\underbrace{{\it n} ,=, {\bf \color{#fa0}e}cd}_{\large \bf \color{#fa0}{e,=,ab}\bmod 4}!$ if $\ \rm \ldots {\bf \color{#fa0}{ab}}cd < 400^{21} \approx 4.398\cdot 10^{54}\ \ $

For example $, n^{21} = 163^{21} = \ldots{\bf \color{#fa0}{25}}63,\Rightarrow, n = {\bf \color{#fa0}{1}}63,\ $ by $\ {\bf \color{#fa0}{25}}\bmod 4 = \bf \color{#fa0}{1}\ \ $

But, how do you know that Carmichael of $400$ is $20$?

@Bob $,\lambda(2^4 5^2) = {\rm lcm}(\phi(2^4)/2,\phi(5^2)) = {\rm lcm}(4,,4\cdot 5)=20,,$ cf. said Carmichael link. $\ \ $

Very nice, as always.

Yes, $400$ is easier than $100$ (+1)

Since $\gcd(n,10)=1$ and Carmichael $λ(100)=20,$ $n^{21}≡n\bmod100$,
so the last two digits of $n$ are also $19$.
Can you show that $200<n<400$?  That means $n=219$ or $n=319$.
But $219$ is a multiple of $3$, and $n^{21}$ is not.

I added an answer which explains how this is nothing but a special case of the general method of taking $k$'th roots $!\bmod m$ whenever $k$ is coprime to $,\phi(m),$ (or $,\lambda(m))\ \ $

Calculating that $53$ digit integer $!\bmod 3$ is too much work. Easier: from $,\ldots {\bf \color{#fa0}{27}}19,$ we need only compute $,{\bf \color{#fa0}{27}}\bmod 4,,$ and this method works generally - see my comments on my answer. $\ \ $

The number of digits on the right-hand side is $53$. So,
$$\lfloor \log_{10}n^{21}\rfloor+1=53\implies52\le21\log_{10}n<53\implies299.358\ldots\le n<334.048\ldots$$
It means $300\le n\le334$ since $n$ is a positive integer.
The last digit on the right-hand side is $9$, which is odd. The last digit of $n$ must be odd. The last digit can not be $1$ and $5$. It can not be even $3$ and $7$ since $21\equiv1\pmod4$. So, the last digit must be $9$. It means $n$ can be either $309$ or $319$ or $329$. But observing the first few digits of $n^{21}$, $309$ would be too small and $329$ would be too large (see the logarithmic scale). We can verify that the second-last digit $1$ occurs only in $(3\cdot10^2+19)^{21}$. Hence, $n=319$ is the correct value/solution. $\blacksquare$

We have $10^{53}>n^{21}>3.7\times10^{52}$. Since $3.7^2>10$ we have $n^{21}>10^{52.5}=10^{105/2}$. So $n>10^{5/2}>300$. It is easy to check that $400^{21}>10^{54}$. So the first digit is $3$. As you say, the last digit must be $9$. So $n=300+10t-1$, where $1\le t\le10$. The last two digits of $n^{21}$ are the same as those of $(10t-1)^{21}$. By the binomial theorem,
$$
(10t-1)^{21}=-1+21\cdot 10t-210\cdot100t^2+\ldots=10t-1+\text{a positive multiple of 100.}
$$
Hence $t=2$ and $n=319$.

Pustam Raut reduced the problem by $\log_{10}$ analysis and observing that the last digit is $9$ to one of the cases: $n=309,319,329.$
Since $n^{21}\equiv19\pmod{100}$ and $\varphi(100)=(4-2)(25-5)=40$, we have $(n^{21})^2=n^{42}=n^{40}\cdot n^2\equiv n^2\equiv61\pmod{100}.$ But, only $n=319$'s square is $61$ modulo $100$.
